# AIDL (Android Interface Definition Language) in android studio

Tags: android-studio, java-native-interface, ipc, aidl, android-binder

i am working on jni project and i have header file with global declaration in my native side i want to access all variables they are much more can i use AIDL or Binder here if yes then how and i dont want to change my codebase in native and java side

i tried socket memory mapping but look time taking process

Comment: No. AIDL is supposed to help you construct RPC calls to system services.